# Analysing java heapdumps: why are enum instances kept in heap?

Tags: java, enums, heap-memory, heap-dump

I've been looking for memory leaks in my app and foud with jhat that for some reason instances of enumerations are kept in the heap.

To simulate it, I have deployed my app in tomcat, worked a bit with it, stopped it and performed GC on tomcat (through jconsole). Then took a heapdump and found this:

```
instance of x.mgbean.quote.Input$Tab@0xe0887c0 (16 bytes)
Class:
class x.mgbean.quote.Input$Tab
Instance data members:
name (L) : VEHICLE (24 bytes)
ordinal (I) : 0
References to this object:
java.util.HashMap$Entry@0xe15f7c0 (24 bytes) : field value
class x.mgbean.quote.Input$Tab (84 bytes) : static field VEHICLE
[Lx.mgbean.quote.Input$Tab;@0xe0887f0 (20 bytes) : Element 0 of  [Lx.mgbean.quote.Input$Tab;@0xe0887f0
[Lx.mgbean.quote.Input$Tab;@0xe1541e8 (20 bytes) : Element 0 of  [Lx.mgbean.quote.Input$Tab;@0xe1541e8
```

Any idea how this can happen?

Answer (score 6):

Why wouldn't they be in the heap? They're instances of a class (the enum class), as all other objects. That doesn't mean they could be garbage-collected. Their class holds a reference to each of the instances.

Comment: Well, I have stopped the webapplication, there's no need for any of the classes to still be in the heap. So I'm wondering why they still are.

Comment: Did you undeploy it, or just stop? Maybe Tomcat doesn't make the classloader unreachable until the app is undeployed?

Answer (score 2):

I believe enum instances are treated along the lines of `static` fields for a normal class - that is, as long as the class is loaded they are kept strongly reachable. This is necessary for the ease of use that comes with using enums.